# How to check if bot has permission to add Slash Commands

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

How to check if bot has permission to add Slash Commands
Can anyone give me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible through the discord API. I have found nothing in the official discord API docs or discord.js docs to say otherwise.

If you don't want to reinvite the bot you can always create a new invite link with `application.commands` enabled and use it. The new scope will be added to the already existing scopes.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you cannot check, but you can Reauthorize the bot in discord developer portal by selecting in Oauth Applications.command and bot while generating the link.

Or to check you can try to add slash command to server by [checking the documentation](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html#individual-command-files)